# Is the following phrase constructed correctly?

Tags: grammar

> Knowledge inspire meaningful actions.

Can this sentence be said simpler than that and does it sound correct to native English speakers?

Comment: Cascabel, oh I'm sorry. I was simply woundering if the phrase above sounds normal to a native english speaker, or causes confusion.

Comment: Can you tell us why you think it's correct to pair the singular noun "Knowledge" with the plural verb form "inspire"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say *knowledge **can** inspire meaningful actions*

Without *can* the sentence feels choppy and incomplete when spoken out loud.

This sentence would also work by making *inspire* plural (inspires).

Thus, the sentence can also be *knowledge inspire**s** meaningful actions*

Comment: I know you are new, and we do appreciate having you here, but answering close-worthy questions such as this one is not actually kosher. Please have a look at our [Help Page](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) about what types of questions are acceptable, and those [which are not](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: @Cascabel I read the help page and I'm not quite clear what you are trying to accomplish with this comment. Is this directed toward the answer (if so please tell me specifics to improve) or toward the question itself. What do you mean by 'close-worthy' questions?

Comment: Please see the part about "Proofreading ("Is this right?", "Are there any mistakes?"), unless a specific source of concern is clearly specified. See below for hints on checking existing texts." This question is about to be put "on hold", and then closed for lack of research, proofreading, whatever. You cannot see it (I don't think), but if the [close] tag opens between "edit" and "flag", it generally gets closed

Comment: FYI: sticking an _s/es_ on a verb doesn't make it plural, but singular. We go, they go, but he goes.